# Trouble simplifying a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$F(p) = \frac{\cos p + pe^p}{p^{10} + \dfrac{1}{p^2}}$$

O.K. What a simple function! /s

By quotient law we have:

$$\frac{dF}{dp}=\frac{(-\sin(p) + pe^p + e^p)(p^{10} + p^{-2}) - (\cos(p) + pe^p)(10p^9 - 2p^{-3})}{(p^{10} + p^{-2})^2}$$

Some fractional simplification later:

$$\frac{(\sin(-p) + pe^p + e^p)(\frac{p^{12} + 1}{p^2}) - (\cos(p) + pe^p)(\frac{10p^{12} - 2}{p^3})}{p^{20} + p^{-4} + 2p^{12}}$$

Still very long, still not very jolly. No matter how much I think I can't think of a way to simplify it further. Can anyone prompt me? (Emphasis on *prompt*, please don't give me the entire solution).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For instance, multiply numerator and denominator by $p^4$, so that you cancel the fractions in the numerator and you remove negative exponents in the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it as
$$
F(p)=\frac{p^2\cos p+p^3e^p}{p^{12}+1}=\frac{f(p)}{g(p)}
$$
and apply the quotient rule:
\begin{align}
f'(p)&=2p\cos p-p^2\sin p+3p^2e^p+p^3e^p\\[4px]
g'(p)&=12p^{11}
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
f'(p)g(p)
&=(2p\cos p-p^2\sin p+3p^2e^p+p^3e^p)(p^{12}+1)\\[4px]
&=2p(p^{12}+1)\cos p-p^2(p^{12}+1)\sin p+(3p^2+p^3)(p^{12}+1)e^p
\end{align}
and
$$
f(p)g'(p)=
12p^{13}\cos p+12p^{14}e^p
$$
Now, just put together the pieces

> $f'(p)g(p)-f(p)g'(p)=2p(1-5p^{12})\cos p-p^2(p^{12}+1)\sin p+p^2(3+p-9p^{11}+p^{12})e^p$
> and, finally,
> $F'(p)=\dfrac{2p(1-5p^{12})\cos p-p^2(p^{12}+1)\sin p+p^2(3+p-9p^{11}+p^{12})e^p}{(p^{12}+1)^2}$

Comment: When I used @AugSB's comment, I got: $$\dfrac{(p^{14} + p^2)\sin(-p) + (10p^{13} - 2p)\cos(p) + (11p^{14} + p^{15} + p^3 - p^2)e^p}{p^{24} + p + 2p^{16}}$$

Comment: @eshansingh1 Why multiplying by $p^4$? Just $p^2$ suffices (which is essentially the same I did).

Comment: Yes, but what I'm more worried about is the disagreeing coefficient for $e^p$. I'm not sure how to check this. Forgive me, I'm not really a math person.

Comment: @eshansingh1 Such computations are always a mess and it's quite easy making some small mistake. I used all the care I could in my answer, but some mistake could have sneaked in nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Let me just have a look through it again.

Comment: My work looks correct. Running it through [derivative-calculator](derivative-calculator.net) gives something very different, though: $$-\dfrac{p\left(\left(p^{13}+p\right)\sin\left(p\right)+\left(10p^{12}-2\right)\cos\left(p\right)+\left(-p^{14}+9p^{13}-p^2-3p\right)\mathrm{e}^p\right)}{\left(p^{12}+1\right)^2}$$

Comment: Oops! I just saw I had made a huge mistake in multiplying by $p^4$. Neither mine nor yours checks out - the calculator is right.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your function as 
$$
F(p) = \mathrm{Re}\left[p^2(e^{\mathrm{i}p} + pe^p)(p^{12}+1)^{-1}\right]\ ,
$$
where Re stands for real part. Differentiating (which is fast using product and chain rule), you will get a sum of three reasonable (at least to my taste) fractions.

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit of a stupid question, but... where did the cosine go in your rewrite? And where did $i$ come from?

Comment: @eshansingh1 Ok, I assume you haven't seen Euler's formula before https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula ... in this case, ignore my answer.

Comment: Yep, though it is very interesting. Thanks for that!

Comment: You're welcome.